# Python raspberry Pi timelapse memory leak?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi

I am using my raspberry Pi3 to create timelapse videos. I have a cron that runs a python script every minute that decides how many photos to take and then imports a function from another python script that takes the actual photos. The problem is that after running for about 4 hours the camera stops taking photos- if I try and take one manually it says it is out of memory, and `top` confirms this. If I watch `top` while the timelapse is running the memory usage steadily climbs.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to the python script that takes the photos. I can run this on its own, and if I start up the pi and run it a few times I see that the memory used climbs by about 10MB the first run and about 1MB every subsequent run (screenshot at the bottom of the post). This is the script

```
import time
import picamera
import os

def ShutterTS(dirname):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
        cam.resolution=(1920,1440)
        cam.rotation=180
        cam.hflip=True
        # camera warm up time
        time.sleep(2)  
        FNfmt = "%4d%02d%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d.JPG"
        Fname = FNfmt % time.localtime()[0:6]
        framename = os.path.join(dirname, Fname)
        cam.capture(framename)
        return

def main():
    dirname = [insert path here, my path hidden]
    ShutterTS(dirname)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm not a good coder, I basically cobble stuff together from bits I find on the internet so I'm hoping this is something really simple that I've missed. The `with` is the raspberry pi recommended way of calling the camera. I know this should close the camera instance on exit but I'm guessing something is hanging around in memory? I tried adding `close.cam()` at the end of the function and it made no difference (didn't think it would). I've tried `del` on all the variables at the end of the function and it made no difference. I think the `return` at the end of the function is redundant but adding it made no difference.

This website https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ suggests that `top` showing the memory climbing is normal and `free -m` is a better gauge, and that shows plenty available- but the fact remains the camera stops working, saying it is out of memory. Any clues would be much appreciated!

This is the cron script (some other imports cropped)

```
from ShutterTimestamp import ShutterTS
from makedirectory import testmakedir
from SunTimesA import gettimes

def Timer(dirname,FRAMES_PER_MINUTE):
    # I take a picture first and then loop so the program isn't
    # sleeping pointlessly to the end of the minute
    start = time.time()
    ShutterTS(dirname)
    if FRAMES_PER_MINUTE>1:
        for frame in range(FRAMES_PER_MINUTE-1):
            time.sleep(int(60 / FRAMES_PER_MINUTE) - (time.time() - start))
            start = time.time()
            ShutterTS(dirname)
    return

def main():
    dirfmt = []
    dirname = dirfmt % time.localtime()[0:3]
    FPM=gettimes()
    if FPM > 0:
        testmakedir(dirname)
        Timer(dirname,FPM)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

[Screenshot of memory use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO7mz.jpg)

Comment: "I have a cron that runs a python script every minute that decides how many photos to take and then imports a function from another python script that takes the actual photos." Show us the importing script. What you've shown us shouldn't cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've added the cron script to my original post, but note the first script seems to cause the memory leak when run as a standalone program taking single photos.

Comment: A standalone script releases memory when it exits, unless something extraordinary is going on.  Is `gettimes()` doing something that uses a non-constant amount of memory?

Comment: `gettimes()` uses the Astral module (https://astral.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to work out whether the sun is up and whether to take photos. I have added a screenshot of the memory issue to the end of the post. 'SunTimesA.py` is the python script that contains the `gettimes()` function. You can see after running this memory use increases slightly, but this winds back as memory gets released. 'ShutterTimestamp.py` is the python script that contains the `ShutterTS()` function. After running this multiple times the memory use goes up markedly, and it doesn't wind back over time.

Comment: An update in case anyone reads this question. I never found a satisfactory answer to this problem. However I 'solved' it when I formatted the memory card and installed a new version of the OS. Once it was all up and running again the memory leak problem didn't exist.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps basing your assumption of a leak on that screenshot might be misleading. It also shows a progressively larger OS cache, which is what the OS does when it needs to and there's memory available.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a wrapping python script which import the script you provide in the question and call `ShutterTS` in a loop. This function does not return any output to main script (just `return`).

If you can observe a memory leak it probably is located in the picamera module.
A workaround it to call this script as a sub-process, not as a function call in the main process. It can be done in a shell script or in the python script using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Thus the memory will be released after each capture.